# Does Ubuntu install alongside Windows 7?

Tags: dual-boot

Does Ubuntu run alongside Windows 7? How much space does it need? Using Windows Installer LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can Install Ubuntu alongside Windows. The option is given while installing Ubuntu.

Comment: The question was not generally about Windows but specifically about windows 7 (which seems to pose problems) - so your answer is not really helpful.